# Magento 2.3 Export All Invoice In Excel csv or xlsx

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, csv

I need to export of all my invoices in xlsx or csv format (33K invoices )
What I want is to export the invoice information in the form of columns: customer name, amount, product...

Is there a way to do it automatically or any suggestions i will appreciate it ?

Thank you in advance.